# Panel control over div is impacting hyperlink within the div as no linkable

Tags: asp.net, html, css, asp.net-mvc, css-position

Panel control over div  is impacting hyperlink within the div as no linkable.My panel is just appear above my div hyperlink  content.
so part of my hyperlink where panel displays not linkable.. but remaining part of hypherlink is linkable

I am not able to add my sample code over here..

Please see my detail post here.. http://forums.asp.net/t/1895787.aspx/1?Panel+UpdateProgressBar+controls+over+div+is+impacting+hyperlink+within+the+div+as+no+linkable+

Comment: Wow. If you want anyone to spend more than 5 seconds helping you with this, you devote more than 5 seconds to your actual question. Tell you what. We'll just do a fair trade. Every minute you devote to writing a clear and descriptive question, I'll devote 1 minute to helping you.

Comment: actually i have piece of sample code to post in the forum.. but it is not allowing due to formatting..

Comment: Please see my detail post.. http://forums.asp.net/t/1895787.aspx/1?Panel+UpdateProgressBar+controls+over+div+is+impacting+hyperlink+within+the+div+as+no+linkable+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misspelled "progress" in the closing `</progressTemplate>` tag.

**Update**

Actually I was hoping that would fix it. Usually if you're having z-index issues *and* there's a borked tag, that's the reason why.

If it's still not working, then you need just need to dig into the CSS of the page and figure out why. The HTML you gave is not indicative enough to know what the issue could be. You want to 1) look at the *rendered* HTML source, rather than your ASP.NET view, and 2) look at what CSS is being applied to *that* HTML.

Generally, if you need to move an element above another that is blocking focus, you just increment `z-index` until you've achieved that. Just bear in mind that the element must have either `position: relative` or `position: absolute` before `z-index` will even apply and sometimes the overlapping element's `z-index` is ridiculously high (1000, 9999, etc.). So you might have to make the blocked element even more ridiculously high. This is all just trial and error stuff, though, so you're mostly on your own for that part.

Comment: hi, i have played around with Z-Index but no luck :(.. Any thoughts/Suggestions?

Comment: Chris, Do you have any idea with my issue?

Comment: After reducing the height and introducing z-index solved my problem. Thanks a lot Chris :)